# Instantaneous Forward LIBOR rate formula under the real-world measure: A fundamental question

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, actuarial-science

We know how the formula of an instantaneous forward LIBOR rate looks like:

\begin{eqnarray}
L(t, t, T) = \frac{1}{\Delta}\left(\frac{1}{P(t, T)} -1\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $P(t, T)$ stands for the zero-coupon bond price at time $t$, with $T$ being the maturity time (the time at which our contract is terminated). Mathematically, the corresponding relation is given by:

\begin{eqnarray} 
P(t, T) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[D(t, T) | \mathcal{F}_t]
\end{eqnarray}
where the expectation is taken with respect to a risk-netral measure equivalent to the real-world measure $\mathbb{P}$, and $D(t, T)$ is the discount factor between $t$ and $T$ (Let's say it is characterized by a CIR model).

My question here is: what if we want to write a formulation for the instantaneous forward LIBOR rate under the real-world measure $\mathbb{P}$. More precisely, suppose that we specify by $P^{A}(t, T)=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[D(t, T)| \mathcal{F}_t]$ the actuarial value of a zero-coupon bond at time t with maturity time T, and $\Delta = T-t$. Then, is it still possible to write down

\begin{eqnarray}
L(t, t, T) = \frac{1}{\Delta}\left(\frac{1}{P^{A}(t, T)} -1\right)
\end{eqnarray}

Please let me know what you think. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you two different treatments, the first from the classic utility theory and the other from financial economics.

1. Consider a risk averse market operating on a concave, monotonic and increasing utility function. Under some regularity (Von-Neumann) conditions, this is without loss of generality. Such a utility function, is unique upto a linear transformation. Then,

$E_Q(X)=P(t,T)$ and

$U(P(t,T))=E_P(U(X))$ imply that

$U(E_Q(X))=E_P(U(X))$

Let $Y=U(X)$ so that $E_P(Y)=U(E_Q(U^{-1}(Y))$

Also $P_A(t,T)=E_P(Y)$

so that we need to relate $U(E_Q(U^{-1}(Y))$ and $E_Q(Y)$. Observe on account of U being concave,

$U(E_Q(U^{-1}(Y))>E_Q(U(U^{-1}(Y))=E_Q(Y)$

and thus the only relationship we can be sure of is:

$E_P(Y)>E_Q(Y)$ where the difference is the well known 'Jensen gap' which depends heavily on the market utility function. You can now plug $Y$ as the stochastic discount factor.

2. The expectations under equivalent measures $Q$ and $P$ are related by:

$E_Q(X)=E_P(X)+cov(X,dQ/dP)$

where $dQ/dP$ is the Radon Nikodym derivative. You can plug $X$ as the stochastic discount factor and thus be able to express the LIBOR forward in terms of the $P$ measure expectation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Very interesting. I only have a couple of questions. Could you please provide me a reference that covers all things you mentioned? For the second treatment, we have a relation between the expectation under measures P and Q. I wonder if there is a close-form formula for the covariance function (it is under both measures or only one measure) and how I can find an expression for the Radon-NIkody derivative.

Comment: here what I am thinking:

Comment: We know that for the Radon-Nikodym derivative the following relation holds:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\bigg |_{\mathcal{F}_t^1} = \exp\left\{\int_{0}^{t}\gamma(s)dW(s) - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\gamma^2(s)ds\right \},
\end{eqnarray}

where $W(t)$ stands for the standard Brownian motion, and $\gamma(t)$ for a kernel function. Suppose that the Kernel function is specified by $\gamma(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\sigma}\sqrt{r(t)}$, with $\lambda$ being the market price.

Comment: In this case, if we want to replace X by the discount factor, then we will have:

\begin{equation}
Cov\Big(D(t, T) , \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big) = cov\Bigg(exp\{-\int_{t}^{T}r(u)du\} , \exp\left\{\int_{0}^{t}\gamma(s)dW(s) - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\gamma^2(s)ds\right \}\Bigg) = 0
\end{equation}
or we should consider 

\begin{equation}
Cov\Big(D(t, T) , \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big) = cov\Bigg(exp\{-\int_{t}^{T}r(u)du\} , \exp\left\{\int_{0}^{T}\gamma(s)dW(s) - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}\gamma^2(s)ds\right \}\Bigg) = ?
\end{equation}

Comment: what do you think? Please let me know.

Comment: Equivalently, we can say that what is the solution for the following expression (suppose $t= 0$):

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[D(0, T)\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}] = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\Bigg[exp\left\{-\int_{0}^{T}r(u)du + \int_{0}^{T}\gamma(s)dW(s) - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}\gamma^2(s)ds\right \}\Bigg] 
\end{equation}

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189009/covariance-of-two-stochastic-integrals - here is how you evaluate covariance of two Ito integrals. You can express the SDF as an Ito integral by using $d(r(t)*t)=r(t)dt+tdr(t)$

Comment: so you think the link can be helpful to answer this question. Because we have the covariance of two Into integral, while in my case there is only one Ito integral.

Comment: The second component of your second integral is deterministic so can be ignored

Comment: I have a question concerning your solution. Could you please let me know why we can say the second equality holds. I mean this 

\begin{equation}
U(P(t, T)) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}(U(X))
\end{equation}

Comment: Bet A is indifferent to bet B iff expected utility of bet A is same as expected utility of bet B. Bet A is the sure amount $P(t,T)$, Bet B is $X$. Since $X$ is priced at value $P(t,T)$, one must be indifferent between the two.

Comment: But the value $P(t, T)$ is obtained under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$, while the right side is an expectation taken under the real-world measure.  If the expectation under $\mathbb{Q}$ is not conceived as the price (the random variable could be any arbitrary quantity), then we can say this again?

Comment: $P(t,T)$ is the price of the contingent claim $X$. Prices don't vary across measures. Doesn't matter how YOU obtained the price. In the real world, people pay exactly $P(t,T)$ to acquire the contingent claim $X$. Also $E^{P}(U(P(t,T))=U(P(t,T))$ as price is deterministic. This is the LHS.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So, under the assumption you mentioned for the utility function, we can say the expectation under $\mathbb{P}$ is greater than its corresponding expectation under the risk-neutral measure. Does this inequality always hold or just under some conditions?

Comment: Holds if the market is risk averse. Reverses if market is risk loving (U in that case is convex).

Comment: Arshdeep, is it possible to provide mathematical proof for the equality (I mean the utility of $P(t, T)$ is equal to the expected utility of $X$ under $\mathbb{P}$ measure) you mentioned? From your explanation, I understood well, but if I want to prove it mathematically, that would be much better.