# Association between a random variable and Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: covariance, radon-nikodym

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable and $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative. The quantity under consideration is as follows:

\begin{equation}
Cov(X, \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}})
\end{equation}

My question is here: Under which conditions we can say that the above quantity is positive or negative?

Comment: This is too generic. Unless there's something specific to those variable, you're basically asking when the integral of a product of 2 functions, one non-negative is positive.

Comment: You can suppose that X is a positive random variable. The reason I am asking this question is here. I want to show when the following inequality holds:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[X] < \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[X]
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ are two equivalent measures. We know that there is a relation between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$  via Radon-Nikodym derivative. In other words, using the change of measures technique, we have that

Comment: \begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[X]  = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\Big[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}X\Big] 
\end{equation}

Comment: According to the covariance definition, we have 

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[X] = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}X] = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}]\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[X] + Cov(X,\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}} ) \\
\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[X] = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}X] = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[X] + Cov\big(X,\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}} \big)
\end{equation}

Comment: So, you see that if the covariance is positive, then the expectation under the risk-neutral measure should be greater than that under the real-world measure, and vice versa if it is negative.

Comment: Is $X$ an asset price?

Comment: Imagine that X is the cash flow generated by a contract. However, we can assume that $X$ represents an asset price.

Comment: I aim to understand when the expectation under the risk-neutralized pricing measure is greater or less than its corresponding expectation under the real-world measure.

Comment: I guess the question is: is $X$ traded (or attainable)? Any traded asset should yield the risk-free rate under the risk-neutral measure. On the other hand, the risk-free rate is the smallest possible return in an economy (otherwise there would be arbitrage, this is trivial). If the asset is risky, then its return under the physical measure $\mathbb{P}$ should be greater than the risk-free one. Hence, if $X$ is a traded asset, we always have $\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}(X)<\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}(X)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. So, this is only when the random variable $X$ is interpreted as the asset price.  In the following link, someone else has proved this inequality using the utility function concept. Do you think it is true? 

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/63851/instantaneous-forward-libor-rate-formula-under-the-real-world-measure-a-fundame/63869?noredirect=1#comment92482_63869

Comment: @Daneel Olivaw could you justify "If the asset is risky, then its return under the physical measure should be greater than the risk-free one" ?

Comment: If the random variable $X$ represents the loss linked to mortality risks or catastrophe risks (which have nothing to do with the asset price), then is it possible to say something similar?

Comment: @AntoineConze This is sort of an intuitive assumption I think and boils down to the concept of risk-aversion. In the physical world, investors are risk averse, and thus by definition will not purchase an asset with higher (non-zero in this case) volatility than the risk free asset unless $\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[X] > r$. I.e. you will only take on risk if you have some feeling that it is worth it to take on risk.

Comment: if the physical measure expected return of all 'traded' assets is always greater than $r$ as claimed above, why would any prop trader short-sell stocks or be the seller of a stock future ?

Comment: Well, no one knows the physical measure - all they have are their approximations of it.

Comment: @AntoineConze as rubikscube09 explained, in a standard utility theory setting with risk-averse investors, the expected return of a risky asset should be higher than the risk-free return, otherwise the investor will simply put his money in the risk-free asset. Even in such a setting, you can justify the existence of short-sellers because of hedging needs I guess.

Comment: @user53249 no, if $X$ is non-traded (such as a mortality risk) then this no longer holds. The underlying rationale is that expected returns will converge towards a "rational" value (based on the riskiness of the asset) because market participants can buy/sell them depending on whether they are overpriced/underpriced, thus influencing their expected return. If the asset is non-traded, there is no longer supply-demand dynamics on its "price" and the "return" is exogeneous to the market.

Comment: Thanks all. It seems that there are different opinions regarding this matter.